# Arch angle needed. Have, radius, width, rise.

Tags: angle

I use auto cad everyday, all day. I am trying to create a excel spreadsheet, where you can type in given information and receive missing information, rather than drawing out the arch.

For example, 35.75" wide x 47.75" over all height and a leg height of 41.75".  This would be an arch.

With the given information, the rise is 6", I can do the math and get the radius, radius is 29.625.

Using autocad, I get an "angle" at the top of the leg of 27 degrees.  I am trying to figure out the formula needed to get the 27 degrees

Tried to post a picture but I am to new to do so.

Although it's fine using autocad to do this, I personally would like to know the formula.

And for this life of me I cannot, and I'm sure it's simple enough

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: What angle are you talking about? The tangent to the curve when it terminates at the leg? Or the central angle of the sector created by the arch?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment

Comment: This is hard for me to explain, this would be where a arch and a vertical meet.

Comment: I think I understand your setup as I calculate a radius of $r= 29,626"$, almost the same as yours. But I cannot find an angle of about $27$ degrees. The angle that the arch makes with the horizontal at the start of the arch is $37.1$ degrees. Is this the angle you are thinking of?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is difficult for me to explain without a picture.  I will try to describe this the best I can.

Comment: It is very easy to post a picture. Edit your post (press "edit" beneath your text), press the picture icon on the bar above your text (to the right of the $\{\}$ symbol) and drag and drop your picture file into the window where it says "Drag and drop or click here".

Comment: @Macee80 By the way, to alert a person that a comment you write is for them, start the comment with the @ symbol followed by their name. Like I did in this comment. They will then receive a notice that a comment for them was made.